# What can be recovered by Akka Future recover?

Tags: scala, akka, future

I'm curious under which situation can the `recover` function in Future recover a thrown exception? I'm using Akka Actor and Future together:

Here is where I made the future call:

```
implicit val timeout = Timeout(5.seconds) //yes, I already have this line.

val response = (ActorA ? someMessage(someStuff))
                    .mapTo[TransOk]
                    .map(message => (OK, message.get))
                    .recover{
                    case e => (BadRequest, e.getMessage)
                  }
```

I'm sending `ActorA` and then map the result into `TransOK` class, and at last I add `.recover{}`.

Then this is the `ActorA`'s method:

```
case someMessage(stuff) =>
      //the exception being thrown here is not captured by Future.recover() method
      //why!?
      val id = if (some.canFind(stuff)) doSomething() 
               else throw new Exception("ERROR ERROR!")

      val result: Try[SomeDBType] = DAL.db.withSession { implicit session =>
        Try(DB.findStuff(stuff))
      }

      result match {
        case Success(content) => sender ! TransOk(content)
        case Failure(ex) => throw ex //let it escalate
      }
```

The interesting part is: the first exception is not captured by `.recover()`. So under what circumstance will `recover` be able to capture an exception? I thought it covers all exceptions happening within the methods being invoked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `recover` function from `Future` is set up to handle cases where the calculating the value for the `Future` itself fails.  Think the following situation:

```
val f:Future[Int] = future{
  val s:String = null
  s.length
}
```

In this case, because the `String` is always null, this `Future` will always be failed.  If we wanted to always have a value for this `Future` regardless of failure, we would use `recover` like so:

```
val finalFut = f.recover{case ex => 1}
```

In this case I would always have a `Future` wrapping a value of 1 if my future computation failed.

Now with `ask` and Akka, there are two ways I know of for that `ask` `Future` to fail.  The first involves a timeout happening.  In that case, your `recover` would certainly kick in.  The second case involves the receiving actor propagating a `Status.Failure` upstream to the sender like so:

```
def receive = {
  case _ => sender ! Status.Failure(new RuntimeException("foo"))
}
```

Doing this will cause the upstream ask based future to fail in the way that you want and for your recover to kick in.  If the actor itself throws an uncaught exception, then the supervisor will restart it (generally), but that exception will not by default be propagated upstream to the future from your ask unless you make that happen explicitly via `Status.Failure`

Comment: Wow! Wow! Wow! Wow! I thought your answer was just generalized, but no. It solves my problem. And it's very straight forward and clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`ActorA` is throwing an exception, so that it escalates the error to its supervisor. You never send a reply for the Future to handle. You could try setting a shorter timeout and see what you get.

This example scala script will show an error immediately, but show an error message after 5 seconds, illustrating that you got a timeout rather than another error:

```scala
import akka.actor.{Actor,ActorSystem,Props}
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class ActorA() extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case "message" => throw new Exception("oops")
  }
}

implicit val timeout = Timeout(5.seconds)

val sys = ActorSystem("sys")
val a = sys.actorOf(Props(new ActorA()))

(a ? "message").recover { case e => "bad things happened: " + e }  foreach (println)
```

Comment: The ask pattern internally creates another actor, and wraps the result sent to it in a Future. It is not able to catch an exception thrown in the actor it sent its query to. This is why the only exception you get will be an `AskTimeoutException`